# Can Tungusic and Mongolic be a language family that has same root

Tags: historical-linguistics, language-families, mongolian, altaic-hypothesis, tungusic

https://drive.google.com/file/d/16qyiuz4-rFJl0W1BHbFxA2Ujv9Qp7Key/view?usp=share_link  Mongolic language family book pdf

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tGPEMAgZRqBiuFT4vJrvf41NXxlANjpg/view?usp=sharing Tungusic language family book pdf

i wonder if Mongolic and Tungusic languages have same root? or are similarities just because of adoption such as in times of Qing empire etc?

I wonder Mongolian change during time. So that did it become similar with Tungusic in time (so this means they do not have same root), or was Mongolian more similar to Tungusic in ancient times (so this means they have same root).
Genetical researches also show same haplogroup for both Tungusic and Mongolic. Which supports their language may have same root.

Comment: Relevant, but different question: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/30530/is-there-a-modern-survey-on-the-altaic-theory

Answer (score 2):

Many people before were intrigued by the same question but the current consensus seems to be that Manchu-Tungus and Mongolian are independent language families for which no common root can be demonstrated currently. Also embeddings into one even larger family, commonly known as *Altaic*, are currently disfavoured.

Note the hedging language of my answer: It is still possible that someone discovers ingenious sound laws and reconstructions that allow a linking of Manchu-Tungus with Mongolian into a larger language family. But clever people have tried to this for more than a century without success.