# was old Mongolic similar to old Turkic

Tags: historical-linguistics, turkic-languages, mongolian, altaic-hypothesis

if Tungusic and Mongolic similarity is just because of adoption, are Mongolic and Turkic related (from one root). But Mongolian changed later and changed much more after Tungusic adoption.

Today Tungusic and Mongolic are much more similar than Turkic and Mongolic similarity.
What about old Xianbei Mongolic language and Khüis Tolgoi Mongolic language. were they also similar to Tungusic? or were they similar to Turkic.

http://nek.istanbul.edu.tr:4444/ekos/TEZ/ET002794.pdf a research (80 common words among Turkic and Mongolic on old stone inscriptions).

http://atalarmirasi.org/tr/17-h%C3%BCis-tolgoy-i-ii-bitig-ta%C5%9Flar%C4%B1ndaki-brahmi-yaz%C4%B1l%C4%B1-metinler Khüis Tolgoi inscriptions.

there are much more common words but these 80 words are only on old inscriptions. Here are also similar suffixes with same meanings.

linguists require basic words to be common
numbers are not same.except 4.
1000 is also similar but linguists accept only 1-10 basic numbers similarity .

Comment: Some hints to improve the write-up of your question: Referencing external webpages without replicating the salient information here is a bad thing because those webpages may disappear at any time. Also note that random word lists don't mean much (words can be borrowed, for example), linguists are looking for systematic correspondences to prove genetic relationships.

Answer (score 2):

For Turkish and Mongolian the situation is similar to the case of [Mongolian and Tungusic](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/45906/9781) asked in a prior question: To our best current knowledge, there is no provable genetic relationship.